# combine regex for RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: java, c#, regex

In Asp.net for RegularExpressionValidator, I need to regex validation for don't allow html tag in textbox having only `<` or `>` or `&#`.

Also, I can validate separately for `<` or `>` with this regex `([^<>])*`
and separately for "&#" with regex `^((?!&#).)*$`
But not able to validate both together. So please suggest me how to fix that problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a or '|' in the query to test for multiple validations.  You should be using System.Net .WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) to remove special characters.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: with use of HtmlDecode it will convert HTML tag into decode form and will insert into database easily. But I need to validate on client side before post to server

Comment: If you are running HtmlEncode like you are suppose to then the character will be removed and you do not need to validate at the client before sending to server.  You can also using the standard html schema to validate rather than use you own validation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
^((?!(&#|>|<)).)*$
```

[**Try it online.**](https://regex101.com/r/OCMHBq/3)

This is your provided `^((?!&#).)*$` modified by changing `&#` to `(&#|>|<)`.

Comment: @BuntyChoudhary You're welcome. If this has helped you fix your problem, [please accept the answer by clicking the ✓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). :)